# saving image in a file in php

Tags: php, graph, download

I made a graph by php and save it as a png file. the code is like:

```
$currentYear = date('M');
      $values=array(
        date("M",strtotime("-5 month")) => $cnt5,
        date("M",strtotime("-4 month")) => $cnt4,
        date("M",strtotime("-3 month")) => $cnt3,
        date("M",strtotime("-2 month")) => $cnt2,
        date("M",strtotime("-1 month")) => $cnt1,
        $currentYear => $cnt0
    ); 

    $img_width=600;
    $img_height=400; 
    $margins=20;

    $graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;
    $graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2; 

    $img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);

    $bar_width=20;
    $total_bars=count($values);
    $gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1); 

    $bar_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,64,128);
    $background_color=imagecolorallocate($img,240,240,255);
    $border_color=imagecolorallocate($img,200,200,200);
    $line_color=imagecolorallocate($img,220,220,220); 

    imagefilledrectangle($img,1,1,$img_width-2,$img_height-2,$border_color);
    imagefilledrectangle($img,$margins,$margins,$img_width-1-$margins,$img_height-1-$margins,$background_color); 

    $max_value=max($values);
    $ratio= $graph_height/$max_value; 

    $horizontal_lines=1;
    $horizontal_gap=$graph_height/$horizontal_lines;
     for($i=1;$i<=$horizontal_lines;$i++){
        $y=$img_height - $margins - $horizontal_gap * $i ;
        imageline($img,$margins,$y,$img_width-$margins,$y,$line_color);
        $v=intval($horizontal_gap * $i /$ratio);
        imagestring($img,0,5,$y-5,$v,$bar_color);
     }
     for($i=0;$i< $total_bars; $i++){ 
        # ------ Extract key and value pair from the current pointer position
        list($key,$value)=each($values); 
        $x1= $margins + $gap + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;
        $x2= $x1 + $bar_width; 
        $y1=$margins +$graph_height- intval($value * $ratio) ;
        $y2=$img_height-$margins;
        imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$y1-10,$value,$bar_color);
        imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$img_height-15,$key,$bar_color);       
        imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color);
    }
    header("Content-type:image/png");

    imagepng($img);
```

Now my question is how to save that image? Instead of showing the graph in a file, I want to download the graph. Please help me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by saving you mean letting the user download it you have to send the content-disposition header.
For example:

```
header('Content-Type: application/png');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=image.png');
```

You can use fwrite to save the file to the server's disk if that is what you mean.

Comment: thanks a lot. I want this. Actually I have confused on Content-Type. Anyway Thanks once again.